# cljsbuild target specific dependencies

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

To add a dependency to a clojurescript project, you can include it with

```
:dependencies [[dependency/thing "0.0.1"]]
```

however, I have multiple targets in my leiningen file for clojurescript

```
:cljsbuild {
    :builds {
      :target1 {...}
      :target2 {...}}}
```

and I would like to have the dependency be only present for one of the two targets. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using leiningen profiles. For example, I have a test dependency in my `:test` profile that is used for my `:test` build but not for my regular build:

```
:cljsbuild {
  :builds {
    :main {...}
  }}

:profiles {
  :test {
    :dependencies [["test-dep" "1.0.0"]]
    :cljsbuild {
      :builds {
        :test {...}
  }}}}
```

The test dependency is only added to the project when the test profile is active, so it won't get added to your `pom.xml` file, for example, and it won't get compiled into your main build.